# Using child_process.exec in Google Functions is very slow and random

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to execute arbitrary user provided code in a reasonably secure and controlled way. I have been doing that using child_process.exec within a Google Cloud Function.

However, I'm finding that the execution time can vary pretty dramatically.

Running a single `console.log` inside a Cloud Function directly, vs within child_process.exec inside a Cloud Function, results in an overhead of 500-4000 ms in execution time.

It seems a little crazy that it both:

1. Can vary so widely.
2. Can take over 4 seconds extra to run in a separate thread.

My guess this is because they are essentially only allocating one thread to the Cloud Function, and my process has to wait around for another on that machine to free-up.

Is there something I can do to even this out?

UPDATE:

So I've been able to reproduce this consistently. It's definitely something causing `require` statements to take awhile inside child_process.exec Cloud Functions when the dependencies are medium/large.

Originally able to reproduce with just using Mocha to execute an empty unit test.

But I created a whole repo to reproduce it better [here](https://github.com/ehacke/cloud-function-latency-spikes)

And a blog post talking about my results [here](https://asserted.io/posts/spikes-in-cloud-function-require-latency)

I'd interested if someone could explain this.

Comment: Without seeing code and knowing exactly what's going on here, there's probably not much to be said.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would like to reproduce it, are you able to provide some code sample?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, the issue appears to be that `require` calls to medium/large dependencies, made inside a child_process.exec call, can take awhile sometimes.

Not sure why.

Cloud Run does not have this issue.

But I created a whole repo to reproduce it better [here](https://github.com/ehacke/cloud-function-latency-spikes)

And a blog post talking about my results [here](https://asserted.io/posts/spikes-in-cloud-function-require-latency)

I'd interested if someone could explain this.